# Rewrite Rule to remove pagination prefix

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pagination, nextgen-gallery

What will be rewrite rule.. or any other trick to change Nextgen Gallery Pagination Name? 
i.e.
http://www.Example.com/wallpapers/category/gallery-name/?nggpage=2

to

http://www.Example.com/wallpapers/category/gallery-name/?page=2

category and gallery name always change according to gallery.

Comment: ¿How do category and gallery name change according to `gallery` and what's `gallery` in your example?

Comment: www.example.com/wallpapers/love/cute-love/?nggpage=2
and 
www.example.com/wallpapers/covers/facebook-covers/?nggpage=2
hope you have got how.. they changes..
first one is normal category.. of wordpress, and gallery name is the name of the gallery.

Comment: I think I got it, but they are not modified in the substitution URI: `http://www.Example.com/wallpapers/category/gallery-name/?page=2` so I don't see their relevance in the question. It looks like all you want is just to replace `nggpage` by `page`, which is the first `key` name. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: yeah.. i just want to replace nggpage by page.. but how i'll do that? thats why , i posted full url to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} nggpage=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?page=%1?      [L,R=301,NC]
```

It redirects this:

`http://www.Example.com/wallpapers/category/gallery-name/?nggpage=2`

to this:

`http://www.Example.com/wallpapers/category/gallery-name/?page=2`

Where `2` can be any value.

Comment: But it works. You may try adding those lines `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and `</ifModule>` at the end to make sure the mod-rewrite module is enabled. ¿What's the error you get and what's the URI shown in the browser address bar?

Comment: You can test it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) in case the module is not enabled.

Comment: It seems mod-rewrite is not enabled. You should check if `mod_rewrite.so` is enabled in `httpd.conf` and uncomment the corresponding line if is not.

Comment: sorry for so late. But its not working. Other rewriting rules are working except this.

Comment: Could you please further explain the meaning of `...its not working.` It doesn't redirect, you get an error, what? Please copy-paste in a comment the complete URL you are testing with, maybe the redirection is the other way around.

Comment: before adding adding redirect code
`http://www.Example.com/wallpapers/category/gallery-name/?nggpage=2`
after adding redirect code
`http://www.Example.com/wallpapers/category/gallery-name/?nggpage=2`
means nothing changing

Comment: Seems the condition is not matching the query and the rule is not applied. I am not sure what's going on but modified slightly my answer. Please copy-paste the complete rule-set as it is into the .htaccess file. If still doesn't work, the problem is not with the set of rules in my answer but most probably with other rules conflicting with them.

Comment: Really thanks, that you try for me. But its not working. But ok :)
can you help me on this please [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325043/how-to-change-nextgen-gallery-imagebrowser-url)