# How to change NextGen Gallery ImageBrowser URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, nextgen-gallery

I'm using latest version of NextGen Gallery (Wordpress). When i apply imagebrowser instead of jQuery it changes the image to image page. The url of image page is like

`www.example.com/postname/category/?pid=no.`

but i want to change it into

`www.example.com/image/no.`

Any trick or .htaccess Rewrite Code for doing this?

Comment: If that's in a WP install, you have to take into account the WP redirection code. Please update your answer with the whole .htaccess file where the WP rule-set is.

Comment: [here](http://codepad.org/jQdK72wr)

Comment: the postname is the slug of the post and category is the slug of category and pid is the number of picture which is generated by nextgen gallery

Comment: @faa i got the solution method, will you help?

Comment: Sure, if I can. But, something is not quite clear yet. Assuming the request is `www.example.com/image/no` and the silently mapped URL is `www.example.com/postname/category/?pid=no`, the parameters in both URLs (Request and rewritten) are different. The only one that can be passed is `no`. `image` is not in the substitution URL and has no use. Finally, `postname` and `category` are not in the request, so they can't be passed either to the substitution URL.

Comment: The parameters should match or removed when they are not used, but I guess the 3 are needed so the request should hold them to be able to pass them. Don't need to have the same names, though. Can be identified by the position in the URL structure of the request, as long as it is defined previously.

Comment: there is two type of urls in imagebrowser
1. with slug
2. without slug 
with slug , will show image name in url with this pattern
`www.example.com/wp-permalink/nggallery/image/pic-name`
without slug it will
`www.example.com/wp-permalink/?pid=1`
i've set wp-permalinks like `category/postname`
so i need second one url pattern but something like this
`www.example.com/image/1`
and here is the php file which is generating the urls (i found it after checking every file) 
http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/nextgen-gallery/trunk/lib/rewrite.php